# Wordpress: disable wptexturize globally

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress page with the title "Paper 10x10". In my sidebar navigation this page is displayed as "Paper 10×10" (note that the x is texturized by Wordpress and therefor the x became a multiplication sign ×).

I have the plugin **raw html** plugin installed. It only disables wptexturizing for `the_content`. But the navigation is not in `the_content` but in `get_sidebar()`.

I tried remove_filter:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');
```

But this also only disables texturizing for the content or the excerpt.

How can I disable the `wptexturize` filter globally in my Wordpress blog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
remove_filter('the_title', 'wptexturize');
```

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. stupid me. embarrassing i didn't try it beforehand. sorry for your time guys and thanks again windyjonas!

Answer (score 14):

You can disable it globally with the `run_wptexturize` filter, [as detailed here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/run_wptexturize):

`add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );`

Comment: This is the only way to make sure a plugin doesn't inadvertently turn the wptexturize filter back on, and it disables the filter globally.

Comment: Wow! As far as I can tell this is way better than the other solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I went to `/wp-includes/default-filters.php` and looked for everything affected by `wptexturize`, and did a `foreach` in the same style `default-filters.php` uses to add filters.

Your problem seems to have been solved, but others might eventually want the complete purge, so I'm posting it here, it being the first question to come up when searching for `wptexturize`:

```
$filters_to_remove = array(
  'comment_author', 'term_name', 'link_name', 'link_description', 'link_notes', 'bloginfo', 'wp_title', 'widget_title',
  'single_post_title', 'single_cat_title', 'single_tag_title', 'single_month_title', 'nav_menu_attr_title', 'nav_menu_description',
  'term_description',
  'the_title', 'the_content', 'the_excerpt', 'comment_text', 'list_cats'
);

foreach ($filters_to_remove as $a_filter){
  remove_filter($a_filter, 'wptexturize');
}
```

Comment: Does this cause an issue if one of the filters does not exist? Will it cause a php error? I'm concerned if a filter disappears in an update. Also this is not stopping wp from adding double quotes around text in my paragraph tags. Is there another filter for that?

Comment: Never mind about the quotes. That was chrome devtools. But I still wonder if in the foreach there should be a check to make sure the filter exists. Just not sure at the moment how to do that.

Comment: On the documentation on remove_filter, it says it just returns false on failure, so no ugly php warnings everywhere on your site after a WordPress update.You can see it here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

and here, lines 240 to 273:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/plugin.php#L0

Comment: I see that. No warning on failure. And if something doesn't get remove then we know it got added at some point after the removal and know what to look for. Putting this at the end of functions.php should work in most cases. I would have chosen this as the answer since it actually answers the question in the title. Thanks Pabbles

Comment: You're welcome ^_^
I kind of came in three years late with my answer, though, maybe those functions worked differently back then :P